# Work item's URL from VSTS to EXCEL (TFS Office Integration)

Tags: excel, api, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm actually searching if it's possible to get work item's URL from VSTS and export them in a new column in excel with TFS Office Integration.

I've search in google and VisualStudio documentation and I didn't find my answer :(.

I hope you can help me with that :).

Best regards,
Hugo Lanoix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

I can get the Url of the work item's! 
I can export it with a little prg.

Url returns to the work item in the query section

https://[...].visualstudio.com/[...]%20-%20VSTS%20tools/_workitems?id=[id value]&_a=edit&triage=true

Comment: Can you give an example of the solution ? I want to export URLs of work items into the EXCEL file, is it doable?